# Qlikview: Matching columns of two indirectly link tables does not work

Tags: datamodel, qlikview

Following is the data model of the dashboard I am facing problem in:

```
http://blob:http://stackoverflow.com/f3e40cfe-e009-4d03-bcf5-b7b4305c18c4
```

Now, what i want to achieve is that in `Case` there is a filed named Manufacturing_Date. And in MWODefetcs there is a field named Defect_Date. What i want is that when ever a record is selected from a table containing cases from `Case` corresponding records are shown in another table based on the exact match of `Manufacturing_Date=Defect_Date`.

As simple as it sounds, i can not seem to accomplish it. I have tried the following expressions to no avail:

`Count({<[Defect_Date_text]=p([Manu_text]),FaultID=,DEFECT_CODE=>}MFG_BARCODE_NUM)`

`sum({$<Defect_Date ={"=$(Manufacturing_Date__c)"}>}Defect_Date)`

Do the 2 tables need to be directly linked. Is it the intermediary iFaults table that is preventing me to accomplish it?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the P() set expression like this:

```
sum({$<Defect_Date =P(Manufacturing_Date__c) >}Defect_Date)
```